# How create table with command python manage.py syncdb with simple name?

Tags: python

If I defined model `Users` and run the command `python manage.py syncdb`, the created table name is `users_users` instead of `users`. How do I fix that?

Comment: specify the table name in Meta class, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#db-table) field in the Meta class for models. You'll want to add a Meta class to your model and manually set the table name:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table= 'your_destired_table_name'
```

[Another example of where the Meta class fits in the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#meta-options).

Comment: Thanks! Work with db_table = "your_destired_table_name", not with db_name = 'your_destired_table_name'